# Programmatically removing all bluetooth devices on the Linux command line

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez, hci

I am able to scan for all available bluetooth devices with hcitool or with my C program.

I can pair the device using it's address with a simple-agent python script.

I would like to know if I can also remove the paired device using either hcitool, hciconfig or some kind of bluetooth command.

I know the information of detected devices for the hci0 controller is stored in /var/lib/bluetooth/XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX, where XX:XX:XX:XX:XX is the address of the hci controller.

This would be useful for testing pairing, connecting and disconnecting devices.

Comment: Could you share with me how exactly do you use the hcitool on OS X to scan for BT

Answer (score 18):

For those using Ubuntu 20.04, here is the same command using the *bluetoothctl* command

```
#!/bin/bash 
for device in $(bluetoothctl devices  | grep -o "[[:xdigit:]:]\{8,17\}"); do
    echo "removing bluetooth device: $device | $(bluetoothctl remove $device)"
done
```

Answer (score 8):

bluez-test-device remove XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX

Comment: (And get the XX:XX:XX:... with `bluez-list-devices`.)

Comment: This really helped me to solve my problem. bluez-test-device command seems to be useful for making bluetooth create/remove/trusted programmatically, thanks.

Comment: What do I need to install?

Answer (score 8):

If you install the `bluez-tools` package, run this to unpair a bluetooth device :

```
bt-device -r xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

where `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is the address of the paired device.

Comment: Works perfectly for me

Comment: Doesn't work if the bt-device has not been installed.

Answer (score 6):

As it is mentioned above on ashish's answer, you can us bluez-test-device to remove the device which that you already know its mac address. So the problem is to parse the mac address of the added devices.

With python or c or whatever you use,

1) list the devices with;

```
bluez-test-device list
```

and parse the output and get all the MAC addresses of the devices, add them to a list.

2) disconnect and remove the devices;

```
bluez-test-device disconnect <MAC ADDRESS>
bluez-test-device remove <MAC ADDRESS>
```

Answer (score 6):

Command using [bluetoothctl](https://manpages.debian.org/jessie/bluez/bluetoothctl.1.en.html) binary: `for device in $(bluetoothctl devices | grep -vEi '(o que mais vc quer deixar aqui|samsung|jbl|wireless)' | awk '{print $2}'); do bluetoothctl remove $device; done`

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, been looking everywhere for a simple solution like this.

Answer (score 3):

All these answers don't answer the headline "removing **all** Bluetooth devices"

I wrote this little bash script to remove all the Bluetooth devices that are listed in the `bt-device -l`

```
#!/bin/bash 
for device in $(bt-device -l | grep -o "[[:xdigit:]:]\{11,17\}"); do
    echo "removing bluetooth device: $device | $(bt-device -r $device)"
done
```

#### How to run?

1. Make a new file like `<fileName>.sh` and paste the code above.
2. Run `chmod +x <fileName>` to make the script executable
3. Run `./<fileName>.sh`
4. Celebrate! All Bluetooth devices are removed now :)

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Jesse de gans' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65006935/4447317) here is a one-liner to **disconnect** all devices for both [bt-device](https://www.mankier.com/1/bt-device) and [bluetoothctl](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth).

```bash
# disconnect all devices using bt-device
for device in `bt-device -l`; do [[ "$device" =~ ([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}) ]] && bt-device -d $(echo $device | sed 's/[()]//g'); done

# disconnect all devices using bluetoothctl
for device in `bluetoothctl paired-devices`; do [[ "$device" =~ ^([0-9A-Fa-f]{2}[:-]){5}([0-9A-Fa-f]{2})$ ]] && bluetoothctl disconnect $device; done
```

It's a little more work for bt-device as the MAC addresses are wrapped in parenthesis `()` so we need to use sed to strip them.